# If $g$ is Riemann integrable and $g\ge f\ge 0$, then $f$ is also Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

We are told that $g(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)=0$ also that $0≤f(x)≤g(x)$ and asked to prove $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable and that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=0$.

Intuitively $g$ must be a special kind of function, like $0$, or $0$ with 'spikes' or perhaps if not, then $a=b$.

But how to start a proof? Direction appreciated.

Comment: Do you work with Riemann or Lebesgue integration?

Comment: Note if $g(x) >0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b g(x)dx>0$. So all $<$ should be changed to $\le $.

Comment: That $g(x)$ what on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Riemann. Corrected as prompted.

Comment: $$0\leqslant f\leqslant g\implies\int_a^b0\,dx\leqslant\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\leqslant\int_a^bg(x)\,dx$$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Relevant?

Comment: @Did Yes. I am more comfortable with Lebesgue integrals, and if he were too, then that's the answer I would give.

Comment: To show that $f$ Riemann integrable it is essential to use that $\int_a^b g(x)dx = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm considering Darboux sums. For any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ we have
$0\leq U(f,P)\leq U(g,P)$. Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there is a partition $P_*$ such that 
$$0\leq U(f,P_*)\leq U(g,P_*)<\epsilon\ .$$
This shows that $\>\inf_P U(f,P)\leq\epsilon$, and as $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we have
$$0\leq\sup_P L(f,P)\leq\inf_P U(f,P)\leq0\ ,$$
which proves the claim.